# #Azure tenant problem in local jupyter notebook server

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have upgraded my subscription from "azure for students" to "pay as you go" but when i try to create workspace using jupyter local notebook server i am getting a user error which says You are currently logged-in to ... tenant you don't have access to .... subscription, please check if it is in this tenant., i was able to create my workspace using azure portal but i want to create my workspace using jupyter local notebook server, how to fix that error?

[user error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jav7P.png)
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiBPB.png)

Answer (score 4):

I Had the same issue and found out that azure ml was using my default tenant. I had to specify the tenant Id I want to use.

```
interactive_auth = InteractiveLoginAuthentication(tenant_id="my-tenant-id")
ws = Workspace(subscription_id="my-subscription-id",
               resource_group="my-resource-group",
               workspace_name="my-workspace",
               auth=interactive_auth)
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue usually occurs if you selected the wrong directory, or your account doesn't have sufficient permissions. To fix this issue, first ensure that you have selected the correct directory and have your resources in that directory by clicking your account at the top right.

[image]

If you still see that message, make sure that you have the Owner role assigned to your account by going to All Services > Subscriptions > your subscription that you want access to > Access control (IAM) > Role assignments > Add > [Add role assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal).

Refer to [the guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/quickstart-run-local-notebook) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, did that but problem is still there, any other solution for this problem?